# Why java packages do not work as a hierarchy?

Tags: java, package

why java does not allow access to package restricted types that are in parents package?

With something like :

```
Package a
|--Class A
|--Package b
   |--Class B
```

It is not possible to access class `A` from class `B` if class `A` has package visibility. I thought it make sense but apparently not.

What is the reason for that?

Comment: Because that's how Java access modifiers are [specified to work](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-6.html#jls-6.6). Would it make sense to be like you expect? Perhaps; but it's not.

Comment: The JLS explicitly states: "The hierarchical naming structure for packages is intended to be convenient for organizing related packages in a conventional manner, but has no significance in itself other than the prohibition against a package having a subpackage with the same simple name as a top level type (§7.6) declared in that package." Any answer trying to discern *why* that statement is there is more likely to be guesswork than concrete fact.

Comment: Come on, stop with the -1, I'm asking why java was conceived that way.

Comment: "I'm asking was java was conceived that way" You'd have to ask James Gosling et al. We can only guess.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no such thing as a parent package or child package. Packages are **not** a hierarchic thing. Each package is self-contained. That packages that follow a hierarchic naming pattern are also stored in a hierarchic filesystem hierarchically is just convention.

From [JLS Sec 7.1](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-7.html#jls-7.1):

> The hierarchical naming structure for packages is intended to be convenient for organizing related packages in a conventional manner, but has no significance in itself other than the prohibition against a package having a subpackage with the same simple name as a top level type (§7.6) declared in that package.
>
> *For example, there is no special access relationship between a package named `oliver` and another package named `oliver.twist`, or between packages named `evelyn.wood` and `evelyn.waugh`. That is, the code in a package named `oliver.twist` has no better access to the types declared within package `oliver` than code in any other package.*